# fireplace gas pipe coming from the floor of the box

Tags: gas, fireplace

I have a fireplace t bar coming up through the bottom of my fireplace, I am trying to install a gas log however they are telling me this pipe needs to come through the side wall, is this possible? Talked to a plumber he won't touch it

Comment: Find a plumber that will.

Comment: i think that you need a gas fitter

Comment: Providing make & model of the fireplace and the gas log may help get you a better answer here. Did you ask the plumber _why_ he won't touch it? Maybe the piping is in a sorry state and he doesn't want to rip out the whole thing...

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible that the pipe needs to come through the side of the fireplace, if it's possible to move it, or if it's actually necessary for the pipe to come from there?

Comment: I did seek help from a plumber one that does gas lines I don't think he really wanted to tackle the job  had to call him twice before I got a response and he wasn't willing to come out and look at the job, the gas meter is on the outside left wall (of the fireplace) so I don't understand why they can't take the line off the meter and drill through the fireplace? Thsi house was built in the early 60's . My plumber said the existing would just be capped offf. The guy that called said 2,500 minimum, lol without even looking at it. The log set is a petersen charred oak. I luv wood but  lungs don't

Comment: The gas line per the fire gas long installer said the line must come from the side, mine is coming up from the floor of the fireplace towards the front in a T shape, he is stating the line would be in front of the log set :(